# Connection refused while sending an email?

Tags: java, spring, email, java-ee-6

I am using spring `org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender` and i have below configuration.

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="my.host.net"/>  
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <!-- Use SMTP-AUTH to authenticate to SMTP server -->
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">false</prop>
                <!-- Use TLS to encrypt communication with SMTP server -->
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
  </bean>
```

If the application is deployed on tomcat then mail will be sent properly but if i run the `junit test case` to send an email then it says `connection refused` . Am i missing anything here?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a mail server running at my.host.net:25 ?

Comment: Try setting `mail.smtp.auth` to `true`.

Comment: yes running..if i set it to true then it requires credentials. But if i deploy on tomcat it is sending mails without setting auth to true.. Thanks!